# How do I claim my earned Liquidity Provider fees?

Tags: uniswap

I provided some tokens in [a Liquidity Pool](https://info.uniswap.org/pair/0x64cac8fa24f437ceca90e20a7a24a609f162b0d1) for some time, and now Uniswap says I accumulated about 130$ worth of ETH and PRQ on the provider fees.

[image]

How do I claim these 0.113 WETH and 111 PRQ? There don't seem to be any corresponding button in Uniswap webapp and zero info anywhere I look...

Do I miss some fundamental concept here? Are my earnings claimed in some implicit way perhaps, like when I do a swap or something?

Answer (score 5):

*Answered by my boss*

The earned fees are added to your liquidity: to withdraw them you just remove some liquidity from the pool.

[image]

[image]

Note, that the amount of your liquidity tokens stays same, it's their price what changes after each fee deducted from a swap, as the price is proportional to the [global reserve](https://uniswap.org/docs/v2/advanced-topics/fees/) where fees are placed.